# How to implement consumable In app purchase in react native for Android?

Tags: react-native, in-app-purchase, react-native-iap

I am trying to implement a consumable in app purchase in my react native app, are there any libraries?

I tried using react-native-iap but it cannot handle consumable type products it only handles subscriptions and one time purchase.